# Volt adding multiple class in view

Tags: voltrb

I'm building a website with Volt 0.9 and I'm trying to customize my main.html regarding navigation.

Well, there is and if binding in the :Nav section to add a class. The problem is that I want to add another class with another if binding. I've tried to add a second if binding, but no luck, the

are not rendered when I'm using a second if binding.

How can I do that ?

Here's the file :

```
<:Title>
  {{ view main_path, "title", {controller_group: 'main'} }}

<:Body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <:nav href="/">Hammicus</:nav>
        <:nav href="/tv">HammicusTV</:nav>
        <:nav href="/radio">HammicusRadio</:nav>
        <:nav href="/contact">Contact</:nav>
      </ul>

    <:volt:notices />

    {{ view main_path, 'body', {controller_group: 'main'} }}
  </div>
</nav>

    <footer class="footer">
      <p>&copy; Hammicus {{ Time.now.year }}</p>
    </footer>
<:Nav>
  <li class="{{ if active_tab? }}active{{ end }} {{ if attrs.href == "/" }}brand{{ end }}">
    <a href="{{ attrs.href }}">{{ yield }}</a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the double quotes around the "/"
Replace them with single quotes (so they are properly nested) and it should work.
ie
    `class="{{ if active_tab? }}active{{ end }} {{ if attrs.href == '/' }}brand{{ end }}"`